# AS3 : How do you get specific data from HTML & split it

Tags: actionscript-3, loader

Im trying to get the "Visibility" data from the site for my school project, i have tried tracing , trace(loader.data["Visibility"]); , but it doesnt work

here is the code

```
var url:String = "http://www.bbc.co.uk/weather/1880252";
var reqURL:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(reqURL);


loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, handleComplete);
loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;

function handleComplete(event:Event):void
{
var loader:URLLoader = URLLoader(event.target);
trace(loader.data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There isn't common way or any built-in function for parsing raw html in AS3 (not AIR).
The most simple way in your case is to use `RegExp`:

```
public function astest()
{
    var url:String = "http://www.bbc.co.uk/weather/1880252";
    var reqURL:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
    var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(reqURL);


    loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, handleComplete);
    loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;

    function handleComplete(event:Event):void
    {
        var loader:URLLoader = URLLoader(event.target);

        var rawhtml:String = loader.data;

        // <tr class="visibility">
        var tag:String = rawGetTagByAttrValue(rawhtml, "visibility", "tr", "class");
        trace(tag);
    }
}

public static function rawGetTagByAttrValue(html:String, attrValue:String, tag:String = "",  attrName:String = ""):String
{
    var pattern:RegExp = tag == "" ? 
            new RegExp("<(\\w+)[^>]+?"+attrName+"=\""+attrValue+"\".*?(/>|</\\1>)","is") :
            new RegExp("<"+tag+"[^>]+?"+attrName+"=\""+attrValue+"\".*?(/>|</"+tag+">)","is");

    var result:Array = html.match(pattern);  

    if (result != null && result.length > 0)
        return result[0];

    return "";
}
```

output:

```
<tr class="visibility">
        <th class="row-title">Visibility (E = Excellent, VG = Very Good, G = Good, M = Moderate, P = Poor, VP = Very Poor)</th>
                        <td class="value hours-3"
                ><abbr title="Good">G</abbr
                ></td>
                        <td class="value hours-3"
                ><abbr title="Good">G</abbr
                ></td>
                        <td class="value hours-3"
                ><abbr title="Good">G</abbr
                ></td>
                        <td class="value hours-3"
                ><abbr title="Good">G</abbr
                ></td>
                    <td class="hours-3 empty">&nbsp;</td><td class="hours-3 empty">&nbsp;</td><td class="hours-3 empty">&nbsp;</td><td class="hours-3 empty">&nbsp;</td>        </tr>
```

Comment: ahhh alrighty thank you so much , will research more on to regexp